# IEqualityComparer for SequenceEqual

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iequalitycomparer

In C#, is there an `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable>` that uses the `SequenceEqual` method to determine equality?

Comment: What would it use for implementing `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Not exactly what you ask, but if you restrict yourself to `T[]` (not general `IEnumerable<T>`), you can use `StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(arr1, arr2)` and `StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(arr)`. Not the best solution from the BCL, and not so type-safe (you can wrap it in your own class deriving from `EqualityComparer<T[]>` to make sure it is use on `T[]` only), but it exists.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no such comparer in .NET Framework, but you can create one:

```
public class IEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && x.SequenceEqual(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        // Will not throw an OverflowException
        unchecked
        {
            return obj.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I iterate over all items of the collection in the `GetHashCode`. I don't know if it's the wisest solution but this what is done in the internal [`HashSetEqualityComparer`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSetEqualityComparer.cs).

Comment: FYI the current hashing in `HashSetEqualityComparer` is not what you have here. It's not what you want anyway. It doesn't compare a *sequence* but a *set*- its hash purposely collides between sequences that have the same items in different orders.
Your code here is fine.

Comment: Good implementation, can the unchecked be better off only enclosing the actual calculation which can overflow?

Comment: Note that depending on what you plan to do with the thing, it may be reasonable to simply implement the hash code as `int GetHashCode(IEnumnerable<T> object) => 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Created a NuGet package based on [Cédric Bignon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14675741):

Assembly package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/OBeautifulCode.Collection/

Code-file-only package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OBeautifulCode.Collection.Recipes.EnumerableEqualityComparer/

```
var myEqualityComparer = new EnumerableEqualityComparer<string>();
```