# Calling .Distinct() on enumerables of enumerables

Tags: c#, linq

At the end of my current LINQ query, I have data which is in the form of an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`, with several duplicate combinations.

For example:

```
{
  {5, 20}
  {5, 20}
  {10, 15}
}
```

What's the best way to filter these so that each set is only represented once?  A LINQ answer would be ideal so I can chain it further.

Comment: You need an `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>`.

Comment: How do you define "equal"?  Does order matter?

Comment: @DStanley - It doesn't - I'm currently ordering the data before it gets to this step, but if the equality test can handle it in an unordered manner, I can take that bit out.

Comment: @SLaks - As in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14675741/298754)? (Now that I know what to search for, it's easy to find.) **Edit:** Or as in recursive's below, of course.

Comment: Yes; exactly.  Ideally, the hashcode should be order sensitive (i.e., the lambda shouldn't be commutatibe)

Comment: If order does not matter, none of those will work, because `SequenceEqual()` is order-sensitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you create a sequence equality comparer like this:

```
class SequenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b) {
        if (a == null) return b == null;
        if (b == null) return false;
        return a.SequenceEqual(b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> val) {
        return val.Where(v => v != null)
                .Aggregate(0, (h, v) => h ^ v.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Then, you can call `.Distinct(new SequenceEqualityComparer<int>())`.

Comment: Nicely written, so much so that it's a pity the null checks are missing.

Comment: @Jon - That's not a problem for my scenario, but it's a very good point for anyone using this code later.

Comment: @Bobson: Note that this is order-aware.

Comment: @SLaks - Very true, but since I don't care about order, I can safely call `OrderBy` before passing to this, with no loss of data.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for the feedback. I added some null checks.