# DistinctBy by properties and array content

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class Recipe 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Cost { get; set; }
  //10 more simple type properties
  public IEnumerable<int> IngredientsIds { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get unique list of combination of all properties (Name/Price/10 simple type properties/IngredientsIds) taking into consideration contents of `IngredientsIds`

This does not work:

```
var unique = recipes
 .DistinctBy(d => new
  {
     d.Name,
     d.Cost,
     // 10 more properties
     d.IngredientsIds
  });
```

I was trying to create and apply a comparer but unsuccessfuly.

Here is a similar subject but I can't apply it on more complex type...
[Calling .Distinct() on enumerables of enumerables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549787/calling-distinct-on-enumerables-of-enumerables)

**More info:** The values stored in the `IngredientsIds` property can't repeat, but can be in different order.

Comment: Did you fail to create a comparer or fail to apply the comparer? If you use a custom `IEqualityComparer` comparer, then you will need the overload of [`DistinctBy` that accepts a comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-distinctby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-1)))).

Comment: Don't `new` an object in the keySelector. Use `d => d`.

Comment: What is the equality semantics of the `IngredientsIds`? For example take three recipes A, B and C that defer only on the `IngredientsIds` as so: A. `[1, 2]`, B. `[2, 1]`, C. `[1, 2, 2]`. Are these recipes equal or distinct?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the underlying type of the `IngredientsIds`? Is it a `List<int>`, an `int[]` or something else?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It's Enumerable, values can't repeat but can be in different order.

Comment: *"It's Enumerable"* -- Do you mean that it's a [deferred enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation#deferred-execution), and each time it is enumerated it hits the database, fetching potentially different IDs each time? I am asking because it might be helpful to know the concrete type that is hidden behind this interface. What do you see if you print the `.IngredientsIds.GetType()` in the console?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise - it's enum class defined in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your linked [`SequenceEqualityComparer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549892/284240) you could create a class `RecipeComparer`:

```
public class RecipeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Recipe>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<int>> IngredientsComparer 
        => new SequenceEqualityComparer<int>();

    public bool Equals(Recipe x, Recipe y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Cost == y.Cost && IngredientsComparer.Equals(x.IngredientsIds, y.IngredientsIds);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Recipe obj)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(obj.Name, obj.Cost, IngredientsComparer.GetHashCode(obj.IngredientsIds));
    }
}
```

You can use it in many linq-methods:

```
var unique = recipes.DistinctBy(x => x, new RecipeComparer());
```

Comment: I'm checking on this, thank you for posting!

Comment: FYI [according to the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083463/distinctby-by-properties-and-array-content?noredirect=1#comment135890746_77083463) the `IngredientsIds` contains values that don't repeat, but can be in different order. Which means (if I understand correctly) that two recipes having the same `IngredientsIds` in different order are considered equal.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: good point. But OP accepted the answer, so i don't know. He needed to create an `OrderedSequenceEqualityComparer` similar to the one linked, but before the `SequenceEqual` use `OrderBy`.

Comment: Yes, although making sure that the `IngredientsIds` are already stored in a sorted state would make things simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I have put `.OrderBy` here => `IngredientsComparer.Equals(x.IngredientsIds.OrderBy(o => o), y.IngredientsIds.OrderBy(o => o))`, much thanks for involvement guys!