# C# Comparing two lists of lists of objects

Tags: c#, list, compare

I don't know where I make a mistake, but i cannot compare two lists of lists of (for example) integers.

Simple example:

```
List<List<int>> A = new List<List<int>>();
A.Add(new List<int>(new int[] { 1 }));
A.Add(new List<int>(new int[] { 2 }));

List<List<int>> B = new List<List<int>>();
B.Add(new List<int>(new int[] { 1 }));

if (A.Contains(B[0])){
    Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
else{
    Console.WriteLine("FALSE");
}
```

returns False. What is the correct way to compare in this kind of situation? I tried also `Intersect` and `Except` with same result.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `A.Contains(B[0])`? Do you want this to tell you whether any of the lists in A have exactly the same contents as the list provided? Identical elements in the same order? Does order matter? What if the list in B is a subset of a list in A? Should that be true or false?

Comment: It's false because it is not the same list reference (It compares the list directly, not only the elements in it).

Comment: The outer `List<>` is not relevant here, your core problem is comparing 2 `List<int>`. And is `{1, 2}` equal to `{2, 1}` ?

Comment: In my case 'equal' means 'same elements in same order'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to visualize this:

```
A:
   A[0]:
       A[0][0]: 1
   A[1]:
       A[1][0]: 2
B:
   B[0]:
       B[0][0]: 1
```

When you call `A.Contains()`, you're asking whether the thing you're testing is either `A[0]` or `A[1]`.  Since you're passing it `B`, and `B` is neither of those two, it returns false.  Even if you were to pass it `B[0]` or `B[0][0]`, you'd still get false, because none of those are *the same object* as `A[0]` or `A[1]`.

`SequenceEqual()` is the function which will test whether the contents of two `List` are the same.  So you want to test whether either `A[0]` or `A[1]` is `SequenceEqual` to `B[0]` (i.e. either `A[0][0] == B[0][0]` or `A[1][0] == B[0][0]`).

The best way to do this is with the LINQ function `.Any()`.  `A.Any(a => a.SequenceEqual(B[0]))` will test `B[0]` against everything in `A`.  If you want to compare *all* `B` elements to *all* `A` elements, you'd need something more like `A.Any(a => B.Any(b => a.SequenceEqual(b))`.  This can be translated as:

```
foreach (var a in A) // A[0], A[1], etc.
{ 
    foreach (var b in B) // B[0], B[1], etc.
    {
       // is our current a value matching the current b value?
       // i.e. A[0] is exactly the same as B[0] on the first pass
       if (a.SequenceEqual(b)) return true; 
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: I suspect, that problem is caused by some kind of reference equality, but i hadn't got any idea how to solve it. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate through each list in A and compare it to B[0] with [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (A.Any(list => list.SequenceEqual(B[0])))
{
    Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("FALSE");
}
```

will return true

Answer (score 3):

```
bool contains = A.Any(a => B.Any(b => b.OrderBy(x => x)
                                       .SequenceEqual(a.OrderBy(x => x))));
```

---

```
 [[1],[2]]    and [[3]]       => false
 [[1],[2]]    and [[1]]       => true
 [[2],[1]]    and [[1],[2]]   => true
 [[3],[4]]    and [[1],[2]]   => false
 [[1,2],[3]]  and [[2,1],[4]] => true
```

Comment: @Jonesy Question is not clear. I assumed `[2,1]` is equal to `[1,2]`. Otherwise `SequenceEqual` would return false.

Answer (score 0):

For reference types other than string, operator == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object. That's clearly not the case here you are comparing one list reference to another list reference.

Comment: It actually (surprisingly?) does the same thing for `string` if it is passed as generic parameter.

Comment: @Grozz - the `==` is applied to the `List<>`s, not to the `T`s

Comment: @HenkHolterman I understand. I'm just saying that if you have generic `Some<T>` and compare its parameter with `==` it will use referential equality both for `T <- List<int>` and `T <- string`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing lists, which by default are compared for reference equality.
For this particular case you can use `SequenceEqual` extension in the following way:

```
bool contains = A.Any(a => a.SequenceEqual(B[0]));
Console.WriteLine(contains);
```

This may or may not be efficient enough for your purposes :)

Another way to approach this is to write your own `IEqualityComparer` wrapper around `SequenceEqual` as described here: [IEqualityComparer for SequenceEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675720/iequalitycomparer-for-sequenceequal)
and then use it as parameter in your `.Contains` call.