# Counting occurrences of the first x elements of sublist in all sublists of the jagged list

Tags: c#, linq, list, jagged-arrays

Im having an empty dictionary:

```
Dictionary<List<string>, int> occurrences = new Dictionary<List<string>, int>();
```

And this is my jagged list:

```
List<List<string>> jaggedList = new List<List<string>>();
```

And x is the number of first elements that i was about to count in the jagged list. In this example:

```
x=2;
```

But i want it to change it myself whenever i get a "thicker" sublists than x+1

Jagged list:

```
{ cc kk ww }
{ cc kk aa }
{ cc oo ll }
{ cc jj oo }
{ ww oo kk }
{ ww oo gg }
{ ww gg kk }
{ kk ll oo }
{ ll kk nn }
{ mm nn oo }
{ mm nn jj }
```

I am completely hopeless with LINQ so i can not do it myself. I want my `occurrences` dictionary to get grouped `x` indexed elements in `TKey`and its occurrences count in the `TValue`, so the result would look like:

```
Keys:     Values:
{ cc kk }   2  //because those appear together in this order in 2 sublist(s)
{ cc oo }   1  //because those appear together in this order in 1 sublist(s)
{ cc jj }   1  //et cetera
{ ww oo }   2
{ ww gg }   1
{ kk ll }   1  //<-note that those do not appear in this order twice
{ ll kk }   1  
{ mm nn }   2
```

As a hint i also have a linq command that does the same, except not with lists of string but with regular strings:

The strings i was talking about:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

{ gg }
{ gg }
{ jj }
{ ww }
{ ww }
{ jj }
{ mm } 
{ ww }
{ ll }
{ kk }
{ ll }
```

Linq command:

```
var dic = list.GroupBy(b => b).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

The dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> otherOccurrences = dic;
```

Result of it:

```
Keys:     Values:
{ gg }      2      //because it appears in this list 2 time(s)
{ jj }      2      //same with this one
{ ww }      3      //et cetera
{ mm }      1
{ ll }      2
{ kk }      1
```

I would really appreciate the help with editing the specified `linq` command to get the one that would analogically do to the same to my `occurrences`. Feel free to correct me if im wrong somewhere. Im sorry if i did not make myself clear, feel free also to ask if you did not understand so i can explain it more specificly.

Comment: Try this `jaggedList.GroupBy(lst => string.Join("", lst.Take(x)))
        .ToDictionary(el => el.Key, el => el.Count());`

Comment: I checked couple of times your solution, turns out it you did it like my list was Dictionary<string, int> occurrences = new Dictionary<string, int>(); Instead of Dictionary<List<string>, int> occurrences = new Dictionary<List<string>, int>(); I didnt want x elements concatenated into one but literally x elements as a list. Could you help me again by fixing that?

Comment: Its probably my fault by putting broken declaration that had list on the left side and string on the right. Sorry.

Comment: as i see you managed to solve you problem, you can post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem to tackle is equality. Two "identical" lists aren't equal. Even if they contain the same elements, they're still different objects. You have to supply an `IEqualityComparer` to the `GroupBy` function:

```
var n = 2;
var dic = list.Select(l => l.Take(n))
              .GroupBy(b => b, new IEnumerableComparer<string>())
              .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

The `IEnumerableComparer` compares lists by their contents. There can be many ways to implement it. One decent example is here: [IEqualityComparer for SequenceEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14675720/861716).

Comment: Id rather do it like @tchelidze did, except he made a mistake i just noticed. He did it like my dictionary had string as a key so he concatenated x elements into one instead of literally adding x elements as a list, like my dictionary is declared (Dictionary<List<string>, int> occurrences = new Dictionary<List<string>, int>();)