# List of objects equality using .GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, object, json.net, hashcode

I would like to understand how the `GetHashCode` method works on lists of objects for equality. Given this example:

```
var user1 = new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Chris" };
var user2 = new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Jeff" };

var userList1 = new List<User> { user1, user2 }.OrderBy(o => o.Id);
var userList2 = new List<User> { user1, user2 }.OrderBy(o => o.Id);

var usersList1Hash = userList1.GetHashCode();
var usersList2Hash = userList2.GetHashCode();

var userListsEqual = usersList1Hash == usersList2Hash; // false

var userList1Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList1);
var userList2Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList2);

var usersList1JsonHash = userList1Json.GetHashCode();
var usersList2JsonHash = userList2Json.GetHashCode();

var userListsJsonEqual = usersList1JsonHash == usersList2JsonHash; // true
```

1. Why are the lists of objects **not equal** when comparing the hash codes?
2. Why are the list of objects **equal** when serializing to JSON strings and comparing the hash codes?

Comment: What you're seeing is the diffference between `Object.GetHashCode()` and `String.GetHashCode()`.

Comment: While the lists are of the same type and contain the same objects in the same order, they are not considered equal according to their hash code. See also http://www.ideone.com/kE2gSj.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ah, okay! But what makes the `object` hashes different?

Comment: `object.GetHashCode()` generates a hash of the object reference.  2 instances = 2 different references.

Comment: That's great. Thanks @Oliver

Comment: If you want an example of a hash function for the *contents* of a list (rather than just for the object reference) see e.g. [IEqualityComparer for SequenceEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14675720/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

`GetHashCode` function gives signed int32 hash of an object.

From MSDN.

> Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However,
>   the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object
>   equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash
>   codes.

`GetHashCode` is a virtual function and can be overridden. What you get after calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` function a string. `string` class has its own implementation of `GetHashCode` which is based on contents of a string. Something like below. That's why it matches.

```
public class string {  
  char[] str = null;
  ...
  public string(char[] input) {
    this.str = input;
  }

  public override GetHashCode() {
    //Logic to convert str to int 32 based on string contents;

    return Convert.ToInt32(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: *"If hash of two objects is equal then objects are equal."* This is wrong. If the hash of two objects is equal, then (with a well distributed hash function) the objects are likely, but not guaranteed to be equal. This is a highly important distinction.

Comment: @spender right. That's what I wanted to write. I updated the answer.